# Contact form 7 in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Actually sir  I am using a make an appointment form in my WordPress website which comes under contact form 7 in make an appointment form
Your name 
Your email I'd
Your address​
Your nmbr
Device type
Device model
Device type 
These text areas are given but sir I want in device model 3,4
Devices are given sir I want to make device model like text area bt that doesn't happening sir what I do

Comment: Share the code that you see in the panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want appointment form like attached the image.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLAos.png
You can use below code

Your name (required)
[text* your-name class:required "John Smith"]

Your Email (required)
[email your-email class:required "example@example.com"]

Your Message (required)
[textarea your-message]Your Message[/textarea]

Select Divice (required)
[select* your-device "Iphone" "Samsung" "Huawei"]

[submit "Send"]